# post and save appended radio buttons into database?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have text fields and group av radio buttons like this

```
<div class="col">
    <input type="text" name="deliveryCompany[]" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="col">
    <input type="text" name="deliveryContactPerson[]" class="form-control">
</div>

<!-- Delivery method -->
<fieldset class="form-group border p-2">
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="deliveryMethod[]" value="Bid">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="deliveryMethod1">Bid</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="deliveryMethod[]" value="Mail">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="deliveryMethod2">Mail</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="deliveryMethod[]" value="retrieved">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="deliveryMethod3">retrieved</label>
</div>
```

I then have a button linked to a jQuery function that duplicates the HTML code above so the user can add more addresses.

I save it to the database like this (I have striped some code)

```
public function addDeliveryAddress()
    {
        for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST["deliveryContactPerson"]); $i++) {

        'INSERT INTO address.....;

$deliveryParamValue = array(
            "Delivery",
            $_POST["deliveryContactPerson"][$i],
            $_POST["deliveryCompany"][$i],
            $_POST["deliveryMethod"][$i],
            );
        }
 }
```

I have one address everything is fine.

If I add two or more addresses I get the contact person and company in the database but nothing from the radio button.

Should I post multiple radio buttons with the same `name` and get more than the first one?

Think I need to post `deliveryMethod[]` in another way but how?

Comment: Have you debugged and checked what `$_POST["deliveryMethod"]` actually contains when the form is submitted?

Comment: Is there more to your form? Because if you just copy the exact code from the question, the page will treat it all as a one big radio button (since they all have the same name).

Comment: I post the name as an array, that's way I can have the same name but I also post the rest as array and I guess that's the problem.

Comment: Partly. But as El_vanja says unless you give your copies of the radio button new names, you won't even be able to select separate options for each set. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/054m62z9/  - try selecting a value in the first set of buttons and then selecting a value in the second set, and see what happens to your first selection. It happens because they all have the same name. Therefore the issue is happening before you even submit. Unless of course, your JavaScript code does something to alter those names when it copies the HTML?